How to make a simple connection from web3 to an HTML site and payment using BNB?
I want to make a simple payment via BNB on my HTML website. The amount is fixed. With the help of which libraries can I connect via WalletConnect and pay from any BNB wallet? Without using server type nodejs on simple hosting using CDN libraries

There is my code on html+js. But this error

getTransactionError.js:7 Uncaught (in promise) TransactionExecutionError: Invalid parameters were provided to the RPC method. Double check you have provided the correct parameters.

Request Arguments: from: 0xccD9131C0949981Ac282b76d98Dd08A14EF25320
Details: Invalid "to" address.
CODE
import {
  EthereumClient,
  w3mConnectors,
  w3mProvider,
  WagmiCore,
  WagmiCoreChains,
  WagmiCoreConnectors,
} from "https://unpkg.com/@web3modal/ethereum@latest";

import { Web3Modal } from "https://unpkg.com/@web3modal/html@latest";

// 0. Import wagmi dependencies
const { mainnet, polygon, avalanche, arbitrum, bsc } = WagmiCoreChains;
const { configureChains, createConfig, erc20ABI, useAccount, useBlockNumber, useConnect, useDisconnect, useNetwork, useSignMessage, prepareSendTransaction, sendTransaction } = WagmiCore;
const { useContractWrite } = WagmiCore;

// 1. Define chains
const chains = [mainnet, polygon, avalanche, arbitrum, bsc];
const projectId = "37568dcda54641e4207bcd3e4d8cf871";

// 2. Configure wagmi client
const { publicClient } = configureChains(chains, [w3mProvider({ projectId })]);
const wagmiConfig = createConfig({
  autoConnect: true,
  connectors: [
    ...w3mConnectors({ chains, version: 2, projectId }),
    new WagmiCoreConnectors.CoinbaseWalletConnector({
      chains,
      options: {
        appName: "html wagmi example",
      },
    }),
  ],
  publicClient,
});

// 3. Create ethereum and modal clients
const ethereumClient = new EthereumClient(wagmiConfig, chains);
export const web3Modal = new Web3Modal(
  {
    projectId,
    walletImages: {
      safe: "/IvmCdGnM_400x400.jpg",
    },
  },
  ethereumClient,
);

document.getElementById("sendTx").onclick = async function () {
  const amountBNB = '0.0001';
  const amountWei = BigInt(Math.floor(parseFloat(amountBNB) * 10 ** 18));
  const amount = amountz * Math.pow(5, BNB.decimals);
  const data = "0x";
  const to = "0xe74D8710769D0Ee7b225165BbC0C2b1e4295B4e5";

  const config = await sendTransaction({
    chain: 56,
    chainId: 56,
    to: to,
    value: amountWei.toString(),
  });

  const { hash, isSuccess } = await sendTransaction(config);

  if (isSuccess) {
    console.log("Success");
  }
  console.log("hash", hash);
}


For making a payment you can do it purely on the frontend.
Use a frontend library like Wagmi to open an BNB token transfer to your destination address.
There is no need for server-side processing, as in this case "blockchain is the backend." and any wallet directly discusses with the chain itself.

Can you provide a small example of how to connect wagmi in html?

Unfortunately getting someone up to the speed from zero is not possible on Q&A website. I suggest you find tutorials and online classes on the topic. If you have zero experience on the matter, it's better that you study it first.

please I have written the code below, please look and show me the error

can you help me?

No it would it take too much time for me. Please go to an online course and learn with professional teachers.
